# Не работает elif после if

Tags: python

У нас есть библиотека tradingview_ta

По задача код должен запускать цикл while true дальше проходимся по словарю и берем значение монет и проверяем его на условие. Если выйдет значение "BUY" либо же "STRONG_BUY" он должен купить и ждать пока следующее условие не поменяется на "SELL" либо же "STRONG_SELL" и продавать монету. Код не должен покупать новую валюту пока не продаст уже купленную. И когда из словаря берет монету и нету условия на покупку он должен переходить к следующей монете пока условия на покупку не совпадут.

Но в моем коде. Срабатывает первое условие (if) на покупку и он не ждет пока выйдет условия (elif) на продажу а постоянно покупает новые и новые валюты. Видимо я условие на продажу поставил не правильно. Помогите разобраться и поставить правильное условие:

```
from tradingview_ta import TA_Handler, Interval, Exchange

last_order = {
'TRBUSDT': 'sell',
'ALGOUSDT': 'sell',
'COTIUSDT': 'sell'}
 
while True:
    for key, values in last_order.items():
        tesla = TA_Handler(
            symbol=key,
            exchange="BINANCE",
            screener="CRYPTO",
            interval=Interval.INTERVAL_1_MINUTE,
        )
        rec = tesla.get_analysis().moving_averages["RECOMMENDATION"]                                    
     
        if "STRONG_BUY" in rec and values == "sell" or "BUY" in rec and values == "sell":
            values = "buy"
            
        elif "SELL" in rec and values == "buy" or "STRONG_SELL" in rec and values == "buy":
            values = "sell"
```

здесь видно что он покупает валюты когда есть сигнал на покупку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

rec - в виде dict выдает 5 значений(STRONG_BUY, BUY, STRONG_SELL, SELL, NEUTRAL)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте поставить круглые скобки вогруг операторов сравнения и проверки, может преоритеты операций влияют. А так вам надо создать минимально воспроизводимый пример демонстрирующий эту ошибку.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с циклом while и условиями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1451641/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-while-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: Предыдущий вопрос закрыл дубликатом на этот. Лучше не дублировать вопрос, а редактировать старый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите менять значения в словаре `last_order`, но делаете это через переменную цикла `values`, которая не имеет обратной связи со словарём. Чтобы поменять значение в словаре, вам его нужно явно туда записать по ключу. Ну и ещё можно чуть сократить повторяющиеся условия:

```
    for key, values in last_order.items():

        ...
     
        if values == "sell" and ("STRONG_BUY" in rec or "BUY" in rec):
            last_order[key] = "buy"
            
        elif values == "buy" and ("SELL" in rec or "STRONG_SELL" in rec):
            last_order[key] = "sell"
```

Comment: Код стал работать. Но проблема с условиями до сих пор осталась. Он покупает сначала все валюты в которых есть условие STRONG_BUY или BUY а потом только начинает продавать их. А нам нужно было что бы он покупал и продавал. Если купил одну то должен ждать условия на продажу а он покупает все новые и новые

Comment: @aktifon Я не понимаю, что вы хотите. Чтобы если есть сигнал `SELL`, то он начинал сразу продавать, даже ещё не купив перед этим данный инструмент? Или чтобы если были сразу оба сигнала, то он сразу и покупал и тут же продавал один инструмент? Но зачем - чтобы заплатить комиссию на ровном месте? В общем, распишите "сценарии использования", которые вас интересуют, только после этого можно придумывать конкретный код.

Comment: В данном коде если есть сигнал на покупку он будет сначала покупать все сигналы на покупку а после покупки всех сигналов он будет переходить к продаже всех купленных валют. Но мы ведь хотим сделать так что бы при сигнале на покупку он покупал и ждал сигнала на продажу. Данный код после покупки снова переходит к новой покупке пока есть сигнал на покупку

Comment: Я хотел поставить условие что бы он по одному покупал и продавал и переходил к следующей валюте. Если к примеру в словаре будут 300 валют и все они будут сигнал на покупку он ведь по условию купит сначала все 300 валют а потом будет продавать эти все 300. А я хотел что бы он по одному покупал и продавал и так по каждой

Comment: То есть если он одну любую валюту купил, то остальные уже не покупать, так? Вообще тут хорошо бы всю логику тогда переделать. Повторюсь - сначала нужно чёткое описание, чего вы хотите. Скорее всего у вас есть сколько-то денег на счету и вы при покупке валют не хотите выйти за эту сумму? Надо как-то проверять тогда сколько у вас на счету и поставить это условием покупки, ну то есть добавить в проверку условия покупки это условие.

Comment: Что-то вы там странное добавили. Покажите пример - что в `rec` вообще, как оно выглядит.

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему в  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1453774/516861