# Ошибка при добавление в словарь

Tags: python, dict

Задача: мы хотим вычислить процент получения прибыли от каждой сделки.

Библиотека которую используем: pip install tradingview-ta

У нас есть словарь с ключами и их значениями. В значениях (values) у нас лист где values[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHam7.png) по умолчанию 0, и values[2] по умолчанию 0.

Мы изменяет значения которые были по умолчанию так:

```
values[1] = tesla.get_analysis().indicators["open"]
values[2] = tesla.get_analysis().indicators["close"]
```

в tesla.get_analysis().indicators["open"] выдает такие результаты float и int (к примеру 0.2233, 199.33, 3400)

Я написал формулу которая полностью работает и выглядит так:

```
from tradingview_ta import TA_Handler, Interval, Exchange

last_order = {
'DARUSDT': ['sell', 0, 0],
'CELRUSDT': ['sell', 0, 0],
'CTSIUSDT': ['sell', 0, 0]
}
while True:
    for key, values in last_order.items():
        
        tesla = TA_Handler(
            symbol=key,
            exchange="BINANCE",
            screener="CRYPTO",
            interval=Interval.INTERVAL_1_MINUTE,
        )
    values[1] = tesla.get_analysis().indicators["open"]
    values[2] = tesla.get_analysis().indicators["close"]
    proverka = values[2] - values[1]
    print(f'ваш процент прибыли: {proverka * 100 / values[1]} %')
```

Но при попытке реализовать в рабочую среду выходит ошибка:

```
values[2] = tesla.get_analysis().indicators["close"]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

вот код рабочей среды в которой ошибка:

```
 from tradingview_ta import TA_Handler, Interval

last_order = {
'DARUSDT': ['sell', 0, 0],
'CELRUSDT': ['sell', 0, 0],
'CTSIUSDT': ['sell', 0, 0]}

while True:
    for key, values in last_order.items():
        tesla = TA_Handler(
            symbol=key,
            exchange="BINANCE",
            screener="CRYPTO",
            interval=Interval.INTERVAL_1_MINUTE,
        )
        rec = tesla.get_analysis().summary["RECOMMENDATION"]                                    

        if values[0] == "sell" and ("STRONG_BUY" in rec):
            values[1] = tesla.get_analysis().indicators["open"]
            last_order[key] = "buy"

        elif values == "buy" and ("STRONG_SELL" in rec):
            values[2] = tesla.get_analysis().indicators["close"]
            proverka = values[2] - values[1]
            print(f'ваш процент прибыли: {proverka * 100 / values[1]}%')
            last_order[key] = "sell"
```

Заметил такую вещь что после добавления в значениях values[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHam7.png) или values[2]. values прекращает быть list. Здесь на фото видно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я заметил что именно после elif перестает работать  values. Он не может не добавить не показать значения. Откуда та он показывает str значение в values[1], values[2]

Comment: Одну ошибку уже вижу: `elif values == "buy"` тут видимо должно быть `elif values[0] == "buy"`, Но вашу ошибку это не объясняет. Можете попробовать печатать `values` в начале каждого цикла. Вообще освойте модуль `logging` и пишите всякие значения в лог. Гораздо проще будет ошибки находить.

Comment: Если добавить elif values[0] == "buy" то перестает работать условие elif. Он не выполняется

Comment: Либо у вас в `last_order` не то, что тут в коде написано, либо вы ещё что-то не договариваете.

Comment: Заметил такую вещь что после добавления в значениях values[1] или values[2]. values прекращает быть list. Здесь на фото видно. Такого ведь не должно быть по идеи что бы лист вдруг перестал быть листом

Comment: А, всё, дошло. `last_order[key][0] = "buy"` и тоже с `sell` надо сделать `last_order[key][0] = "sell"`. Плохо использовать для данных не классы, а вот такие вложенные стандартные структуры. Очень легко ошибиться при переделке кода. Было бы у вас в значениях словаря `namedtuple`, а не список - сразу бы ошибку нашли.

Comment: Большое спасибо. В глубине головы была такая мысль что нужно ведь обратиться к ключу и указать значение [0] но почему то не сделал. Сейчас оканчивал bootcamp python скоро в Data Sciense перейду еще 5 месяцев учиться

Comment: Если планируете дальше заниматься питоном и т.д., то научитесь отлаживать код. Хотя бы просто печатайте значения переменных почаще или пишите их в лог и всё станет гораздо понятнее при разборе ситуаций.